# Partial Power Outage in One Room (and only partially in that room - one half of it)

Tags: electrical

I've looked through similar posts but those cover the entire room being without power; what happens is half the room has a power cut yet the other half does not; it doesn't last long; seconds at most.

How would I go about diagnosing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the breaker/s for that room.  Check the outlets that there is no power with a multimeter or non contact tester.

You either have one circuit for that room or might have two.

Start by removing the outlets and check for loose connections.  If any outlets uses back stab(wire push into holes), change to use the screws on the side.

Do the same with ceiling lights if they go off also.

Newer code uses torque values for tightening screws.  Most newer devices have the torque values on them.  There are torque screwdrivers, so you can do the job right.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you - I will proceed as you've suggested - very good point about having two circuits in the room; I'll have to check that!

Comment: Why you should always double check there is no power.  Having two circuits(or a MWBC) or just turning off the wrong breaker by mistake(done that, been there).